# AdBuddiz ad service or AdMob

Tags: android, admob

This isn't necessarily a programming question but I couldn't find a similar question on SO or searching the web.  I was considering using AdBuddiz for ads instead of AdMob but wanted to get some feedback from others.  Has anyone used the AdBuddiz SDK?  Has anyone had any problems using the SDK or with the company?  Has anyone noticed an increase in ad revenue using AdBuddiz over AdMob?